# How to add custom shell commands to Android Studio Tool menu?

Tags: android, flutter, intellij-idea

I would like to add custom shell commands to Android Studio's tools menu, but I fail to find how to do that. I even would like to add a keyboard shortcut to the command. What do I need to do to add a shell command similar to the Flutter commands in the screenshot?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. Idk if its much help but we use aliases at work from terminal window in android studio.

Put them in your .bash_profile file and then use them whenever you like from terminal

Comment: Thanks for the hint, that works, but would love to have it as shortcut. :)